# Can not run Java Applet in the browser

Tags: java, browser, applet

When I trying to run Java Applet it prompts Security Block which stops running applet in Firefox.  Then I tried it on Chrome, same result.

How can I disable security in java?

Comment: Question already answered in Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/577366/how-to-disable-the-java-security-warning-popup

Comment: Google for applet signing.

Comment: you need to sign the applet

Comment: `How can I disable security in java?` Please don't do that. Sign your applet

Comment: Which Java_version did you use? Since 1.7.0 update 51 the applets need some securitys settings in the meta-inf file.

Comment: I figure out I'm using 1.7.0 update 45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go and click on start button.
2. Type "Configure Java" and Enter.
3. Click on Security tab in Java Configure Panel window.
4. Set security level to Medium.
5. Click Apply, Ok.

Now you can run Java Applet in your browser.

If this is not working try to reinstall latest Java update in your computer.

Link for download java http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your applet so it could be trusted by the browsers either by issuing a certificate from one of the CAs supported by the browsers or sign it with a certificate which is trusted by your internal CA

Comment: thanks for the answer, BTW I'm a newbie in java applets. Any guide refer to java certificates?

Comment: you can check this out https://www.globalsign.eu/resources/SignJavaCodeApplets.pdf